# how to append rows into one row if the other rows have same certain name

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**orginal:**

[image]

**expected result:**
[image]

**Task:**
I am trying to merge the 'urls column' into one row if there exist a same name in the other column ('full path') using python and jupyter notebook.

I have tried using groupby but it doesnt pass me the result i want.
Code:

```
df.groupby("Full Path").apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x)).reset_index()
```

not what i am expecting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is that you need to modify the column for the full path first before passing it to group by since there are differences in the full paths.

Based on the sample here the following should work:

```
df['Full Path'] = df['Full Path'].str.split('/').str[0:2].str.join('/')
test = df.groupby(by=['Full Path']).agg({'url': ', Next'.join})
test['url'] = test['url'].str.replace("Next","\n")
```

This code of course assumes that the grouping you want for the full path occurs in the first two items. The \n will disappear when you write the df out to Excel.

NOTE: Unless the Type and Date fields are all the same value, you cannot include them in the group by since for example, if you did `groupby(['Full Path', 'Type', 'Date'])` you would end up with not all the links being aggregated for an individual path+folder combination. If you wanted them to be included in a comma-separated next line column like the url, you would need to add that to the agg statement and use the replace for those as well.

> Code used for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 999

data_dict = {
    'Full Path': [
        'downloads/Residences Singapore',
        'downloads/Residences Singapore/15234523524352',
        'downloads/Residences Singapore/41242341324',
        ],
    'Type': [
        'Folder',
        'File',
        'File',
        ],
    'Date': [
        '07-05-22 19:24',
        '07-05-22 19:24',
        '07-05-22 19:24',
        ],
    'url': [
        'https://www.google.com/drive/storage/345243534534522345',
        'https://www.google.com/drive/storage/523405923405672340567834589065',
        'https://www.google.com/drive/storage/90658360945869012141234',
        ],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df['Full Path'] = df['Full Path'].str.split('/').str[0:2].str.join('/')
test = df.groupby(by=['Full Path']).agg({'url': ', Next'.join})
test['url'] = test['url'].str.replace("Next","\n")
test
```

> Output

[image: Output of test variable]

Answer (score -1):

Just groupby the FullPath and value as URL field, aggregate with comma separator. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDUSt.png)

Comment: it will work for the duplicate name. i am trying to groupby similar name inside the cell, your result is close but still not in the same row: https://ibb.co/ZHDnBQv

Comment: Please don't paste in images of code or data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question